# AS3: How to save every object on stage

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm trying to make something similar to this:

http://www.personalwine.com/catalog/label_designer_app.php?templateId=5046&action=4C92&userId=0

in Flash IDE with AS3.

My problem is how to save all objects on a stage, save it as a "template" and reuse it again - not as images, but as objects that can be editable again.

Could anyone point me to the right direction on how to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Where?**
You have two choices for saving data, you can either save it on the user's computer (client-side) or on your own server (server-side).

**On the server**
If you're going to use anything that is server-side related well, obviously you're going to need a server (and a database). Using php with mysql is both free and very fast for this sort of usage (small). You might also want to look into node.js since it will probably come very intuitively to an actionscript user since node is javascript and the syntax and structure of node.js files and actionscript files are very similar.

**On the user's pc**
If you just want to store the data on the user's computer, you can use a SharedObject, it will save all the data you need (variables and such) on the user's computer.

Here is a short nice tutorial on how to do so: 
http://kirill-poletaev.blogspot.com/2010/07/how-to-save-local-data-with.html

Here is a much bigger and more detailed tutorial:
http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/actionscript/movieclip-reconstruction-with-the-sharedobject-class/

Basically you can do this for all the variables you want to save (movieclip locations, etc) and then load them. It is very straightforward, you can even store a whole movieclip object.

Comment: Data will be saved on a server in a mysql database. What do you recommend for a type of data to be saved? XML, JSON? Would it be very resource-consuming if there are lot of objects on a stage? Thanks for your previous answer, it was very helpful!

Comment: Personally? I like JSON a lot better since it already is the way data is stored in flash. In a broader sense XML will work too. When you say "a lot of objects" do you mean a lot as in 100 or a lot as in 10000?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a xml save/load function could help. Once one created something on save, all attributes of each object are written to a xml file. If you want to recreate, then you parse the info and build the screen.